# Verb Position in "Ich muss sagen, dass es viel mehr x als y gab."

Tags: word-order, grammaticality

> 1.Ich muss sagen, dass es viel mehr Erbsen gab als Linsen.
>   2.Ich muss sagen, dass es viel mehr Erbsen als Linsen gab.

Was ist richtig?

Answer (score 4):

Beides, wobei 2 hier besser klingt.

Variante 1 braucht man, wenn man den "Nachklapp" des *gab* am Ende einer längeren Ausführung vermeiden will:

> Ich muss sagen, dass es viel mehr Erbsen gab als wohlschmeckende, botanisch
>   ebenso den Hülsenfrüchten zuzurechnende und in verschiedenen
>   Ausführungen anzutreffende Linsen.

Comment: Ich halte "botanisch" für grammatikalisch korrekt, nicht "botanische" - 1 Buchstabe reicht leider nicht für einen Edit. Soll kein Klugscheißen sein, mir geht es um den didaktischen Wert - wenn ich falsch liege, bitte belehren.

Comment: @philerr: hast vollkommen recht, Tippfehler berichtigt

Comment: Rein grammatikalisch wäre "botanische" auch korrekt, allerdings ergibt "botanische Linsen" keinen Sinn.

Comment: @RHa: botanisch ist hier kein Adjektiv zu Linsen, sondern ein Adverb zu ebenso, d. h. selbst wenn es botanische Linsen gäbe, wäre _botanische_ hier nicht möglich.